# How to open a second form based on info from first form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Could someone please help me with the IF-syntax below?

This is what we need to do:

1. Add a new record on `Form1`;
2. Click a button on `Form1` to open `Form2`;
3. When `Form2` opens, it contains info from `Form1`.

So, I add this to `Properties/OnDirty/CodeBuilder`:

```
If me.Dirty = True then 
  Me.Dirty = false
Docmd.OpenForm "Form2",,,"EvalID = " & me!Eval_ID
```

As soon as I enter data, the `Docmd` line creates a

> run-time error 3075, syntax error (missing operator)...EvalID

In `Form1` the key is `Eval_ID` and in `Form2` I have `EvalID` (but not not the key).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this for the OpenForm argument: `"[EvalID] = " & me![Eval_ID]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like there are a few things going on here.  It would also help to confirm some information:

1. Is this referring to a MS Access form or some other VBA-driven form?
2. Are both forms bound to tables or editable queries?

This isn't likely the issue causing the syntax error.  It should be simple enough to resolve that.  Put a breakpoint in the code at that location.  At that point, copy the resulting string (e.g. EvalID = 7) after the word "WHERE" in the SQL view of a new query based on the two tables.  Preview the query to debug the cause of the problem with that expression.

Comment: It is MS Access 2007. Forms are bound to queries.  All I really want to do is enter data on form1, click a button and form2 opens linked to form1.  I thought the button to open the second form could just be a macro with a where statement.  At this point I am open to suggestions..

Comment: Access 2007,  All I want to do is open a from from another form.  I enter data on a form, click a save button, then I want to click the button to open the second form liked to the first.  suggestions

Comment: Does Form2 achieve the desired results if you open it with a filter applied in the form filter property without trying to do so from Form1?

Comment: `Me.Dirty = False` saves the record -- there is no reason whatsoever to change to DoCmd.RunCommand.

Comment: Thanks, @David-W-Fenton.  Modifying post accordingly.